# Retrieving data from Firebase and populate them in listview

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (final DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                arr.add(ds.child("name").getValue().toString()+"--"+ds.child("id").getValue().toString());
//ds.child("id").getValue().toString() this is how i get id from database
                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"id :"+ds.getKey(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
            lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

This is how I get data from Firebase and post them in a listview.
onItemClick I want to show the id of user (from database) in a toast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not to create your adapter's click listener within the Firebase methods.

```
lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String clicked = arrayAdapter.getItem(position).toString();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
            "id :" + clicked,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});


dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        arrayAdapter.clear();
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            arrayAdapter.add(ds.child("name").getValue().toString()+"--"+ds.child("id").getValue().toString());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

> I want to show the id of user (from database) in a toast

Then you can use something like this

```
String clicked = arrayAdapter.getItem(position).toString();
String[] parts = clicked.split("--"); // This is because you added "--" on the other string. 
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
    "id :" + parts[1],
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

It would be somewhat simpler if you mapped your firebase values into Java objects